# elasticsearch query specific or N element in array

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I need to retrieve only specific element in an array of many records.
so below is my data structure:

```json
{
  "creationTime" : "2022-01-01T18:53:34.464887Z",
  "createdBy" : "61c1fcdd88dbad1920da8caf",
  "lastModificationTime" : "2022-01-01T18:53:34.464887Z",
  "stores" : [
    {
      "quantity" : 100,
      "productId" : "61d0b15d7590757ef67ab482",
      "price" : {
        "mrp" : 20.0,
        "sp" : 16.0
      },
      "name" : "Store1",
      "logo" : null,
      "active" : true,
      "location" : {
        "geoPoint" : {
          "lon" : 75.75974300000001,
          "lat" : 26.944576
        }
      },
      "id" : "61d0b1237590757ef67ab480"
    },
    {
      "quantity" : 100,
      "productId" : "61d0b15d7590757ef67ab48a",
      "price" : {
        "mrp" : 20.0,
        "sp" : 16.0
      },
      "name" : "Store2",
      "logo" : null,
      "active" : true,
      "location" : {
        "geoPoint" : {
          "lon" : 75.75974300000001,
          "lat" : 26.944576
        }
      },
      "id" : "61d0b1237590757ef67ab489"
    }
  ],
  "lastModifiedBy" : "61c1fcdd88dbad1920da8caf",
  "id" : "61d0a32f66b7372052a96b20",
  "title" : "Product 1",
  "categoryName" : "category1",
  "categoryId" : "61c2f35b8d22d946e62c6dc1"
}
```

Now, i want to fetch the store nearest to the users location (lat and lon) will be provided in request, and has minimum price. Basically the field stores will contain many elements(store) and i need to just cherry pick the one which makes sense for the user (nearest and  cheapest).

below is the mapping details:

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": {
          "type": "stop",
          "stopwords": "_english_"
        },
        "english_keywords": {
          "type": "keyword_marker",
          "keywords": [
            "example"
          ]
        },
        "english_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "english"
        },
        "english_possessive_stemmer": {
          "type": "stemmer",
          "language": "possessive_english"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "lalashree_standard_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop",
            "english_keywords",
            "english_stemmer"
          ]
        },
        "html_standard_analyzer": {
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "english_possessive_stemmer",
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop",
            "english_keywords",
            "english_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "createdBy": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "creationTime": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "lastModifiedBy": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "lastModificationTime": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "deleted": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "deletedBy": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "deletionTime": {
        "type": "date"
      },

      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "lalashree_standard_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "suggest": {
            "type": "completion"
          }
        }
      },
      "shortDesc": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "lalashree_standard_analyzer"
      },
      "longDesc": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "lalashree_standard_analyzer"
      },
      "categoryId": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "searchDetails": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "desc": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "lalashree_standard_analyzer"
          },
          "keywords": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "lalashree_standard_analyzer",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "imageUrls": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "index": false
      },
      "keySpecs": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "lalashree_standard_analyzer"
      },
      "sections": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": false
          },
          "shortDesc": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "lalashree_standard_analyzer"
          },
          "longDesc": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "lalashree_standard_analyzer"
          },
          "htmlContent": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "html_standard_analyzer"
          }
        }
      },
      "facets": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "specificationItems": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "lalashree_standard_analyzer",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "values": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "lalashree_standard_analyzer"
          }
        }
      },
      "categoryName": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "productFamily": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "familyVariantOptions": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "values": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          },
          "productFamilyItems": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "baseProductId": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "itemVariantInfoSet": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "name": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "rating": {
        "type": "float"
      },
      "totalReviewsCount": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "stores": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "productId": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "logo": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "index": false
          },
          "active": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "quantity": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "rating": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "totalReviewsCount": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "price.mrp": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "price.sp": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "location.geoPoint": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "oos": {
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: Hi @Ravi you should look at inner_hits ( doc : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html ). I think its what you are looking for